# Why isn't spring finding log4j appender

Tags: java, spring, log4j, slf4j, log4j2

In my java main method I have

```
    LogManager.getLogger().error("Log message");
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring_config.xml");
```

Which produces

```
Log message
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

This suggests that log4j is configured fine and the problem is with spring, which uses slf4j.

I don't believe either of `log4j2.xml` or `spring_config.xml` provide any pertinent info. Please ask in the comments if you want to see either.

I suspect the problem is with library versions, possibly some kind of conflict, so you get my maven `pom.xml`, well the dependencies anyway.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.16</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm wondering about slfj4-log4j12 but I don't see anything better. Is slf4j trying to connect to log4j v1? This quagmire of log library versions is maddening.

How do I pacify these warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing a log4j.xml configuration stopped the warnings and enabled spring logging so the problem is with the slf4j implementation `slf4j-log4j12` requiring a log4j version 1 config file.

Replacing the slf4j implementation dependency with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

has resulted in Spring output appearing in the console using only log4j2.xml configuration.